# How to keep documentation history separate from source history?

Tags: git, documentation

I have several small project where I update documentation more often than source.   Because these are small project they have only one directory, where documentation and source files are stored.

Is it possible to have docs and srcs under the same git repo, but not to pollute source history with frequent docs updates?  Or view source history without docs history?  Without overly complicated workflow?  I want docs to be under the same git repo  as srcs.

I've searched SO/Google but have not found solution so far.

Comment: Maybe you can keep your documentation in a separate submodule within the main Git repo?

Comment: Or what about updating documentation in a separate branch, and merging it into master when you're done?

Comment: @Cupcake, I would accepted your suggestion (about separate doc branch) if it was posted in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you have is have is to update the documentation in a separate branch, and merge it into `master` when you're ready.

I'm not sure if it will work well for the purpose of minimizing changes visible in the main repo, but another option might be to keep your documentation in a separate submodule within the main Git repo.

Comment: +1, I've ended up branching of `doc` branch from `master` and  merging it back on releases.

Answer (score 2):

You can do à la GitHub with their [`gh-pages`](http://pages.github.com) branch:

```
git checkout --orphan project-doc
```

The branch will have its own history while being in the same repository.